# SUBSTR inside Like statement

Tags: sql, db2

need to do something like this but i get a CONCAT ERROR, any idea how to do this SUBSTR inside the like?

thanks

```
   select (Select description from BD3 where description like CONCAT('%', SUBSTR(BD3.nomebalcao,locate(BD3.nomebalcao, 'AG. ')+4,5), '%')) as ToGroup
from BD1   
left join BD2 on BD2.group_id =BD1.group_id
left join BD3  on BD1.BPD_INSTANCE_ID = BD3.BPD_INSTANCE_ID
where BD2.GROUP_NAME= 'ADM_SIS'
and BD1.status in (select status_value from stat where name = 'Received')
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query uses some product specific functions.)

Comment: Simplify your problem, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Be careful with your naming. I wouldn't suggest naming a result like a function (`as SUBSTR`) and it looks dangerous to give a result a name of an existing column (`lx.description as GROUP_NAME` vs. `lx.GROUP_NAME`).

Comment: Change `AS SUBSTR` to `AS \`SUBSTR\`` to avoid ambiguity between the column name and the function.  Or better still, don't use reserved words as columns names; `AS mySubString`...

Comment: Also, give the full and complete error message that is being returned to you.

Comment: thanks but i edited my code, maybe is easyer to understand like that. thanks all

Comment: error: No authorized routine named "CONCAT" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: sorry, im using db2 on visualizer

Comment: I've tagged the request with `db2`.

Answer (score 0):

The `CONCAT` *function* in DB2 can only concatenate exactly two strings (`CONCAT(a,b)`, not `CONCAT(a,b,c)`).

Use the `CONCAT` *operator* instead:

```
'%' CONCAT SUBSTR(BD3.nomebalcao,locate(BD3.nomebalcao, 'AG. ') + 4, 5) CONCAT '%'
```

or better even the standard SQL concatenation operator `||`:

```
'%' || SUBSTR(BD3.nomebalcao,locate(BD3.nomebalcao, 'AG. ') + 4, 5) || '%'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, that way works in separate but inside the like it doesnt work :s it return the cell as null

Comment: Are you saying that you can select this expression and it looks good, but when you use `description  like <expression>` you get no results? Then there may be no matching `description`. This can even be a matter of blanks or upper/lower case.

Comment: No because when i do the following query it return on togroup2 but leaves null on togroup

Comment: select (Select description from BD3 where description like '%' || SUBSTR(BD3.nomebalcao,locate(BD3.nomebalcao, 'AG. ')+4,5)|| '%')) as ToGroup,
SUBSTR(BD3.nomebalcao,locate(BD3.nomebalcao, 'AG. ')+4,5), '%')) as ToGroup2
from BD1   
left join BD2 on BD2.group_id =BD1.group_id
left join BD3  on BD1.BPD_INSTANCE_ID = BD3.BPD_INSTANCE_ID
where BD2.GROUP_NAME= 'ADM_SIS'
and BD1.status in (select status_value from stat where name = 'Received')

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Your query is invalid. Check the parentheses. (And your outer join on `BD2` doesn't work, because of your `WHERE` clause.)

Comment: Tried to make it simple,

Comment: select (Select description from BD1 where description like '%' || SUBSTR(Column1,locate(Column1, 'AR. ')+4,5)|| '%')) as ToGroup, 
SUBSTR(Column1,locate(Column1, 'AR. ')+4,5), '%')) as ToGroup2 
from BD1 
where GROUP_NAME= 'GROUP1'

Comment: The togroup2 return LERI, ADOC, but the like (togroup1) returns null